# Mongoose get position of a data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using this code to get my user leaderboard

```js
var data = await db.models.user
    .find({ points: { $ne: 0 } })
    .collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})
    .sort('-points')
    .limit(10)
    .skip(page*10-10)
```

But I can't find how to get users position in the all leaderboard. How can I get it?

Comment: it is already sort by points in descending order, you can do it easily in client side, if you won't then you need to move to aggregation query.

Comment: @turivishal it has like 10k documents. I should get the sorted position in all collection. but  if i don't use limit, it took 20 secs+ to get all data, isn't there a method for it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any good approach or method to do this, but you still want to do it then try using [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html) and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) stage,

- `$match` your conditions
- `$sort` by `points` in descending order
- `$group` by null and make array of all documents in `docs`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `docs` array and pass `includeArrayIndex: 'position'` this will create a ordered index field `position` in each document, starting from zero(0),
- `$skip` and `$limit` stages

```
var data = await db.models.user.aggregate([
  { $match: { points: { $ne: 0 } } },
  { $sort: { points: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$docs",
      includeArrayIndex: "position"
    }
  },
  { $skip: 10 },
  { $limit: page*10-10 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fBqUrqzika1)

> This may heavy operation, might be take more execution time in big data!